# Ember.js: Assertion Failed: An action named 'actionTest' was not found in (generated myroute controller)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm trying to use the component `bs-button` of [Ember Bootstrap](http://www.ember-bootstrap.com/) to dispatch a simple action that will write something in the log. For this, I've created a new app using `ember-cli` and installed ember-bootstrap according the [project Github page](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap#install-in-ember-cli-application).

Then, I've created a route using ember-cli (`ember g route myroute`) and wrote the code below:

app/routes/myroute.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  actions: {
    actionTest(value){
      console.log('on actionTest:', value);
    }
  }

});
```

app/templates/myroute.hbs

```
{{#bs-button onClick=(action "actionTest")}}Run test action{{/bs-button}}
```

But when I try to access, the following error appears in console (nothing is rendered):

```
message: "Assertion Failed: An action named 'actionTest' was not found in (generated myroute controller)"
```

Followed by:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
```

Maybe a completely stupid error, but I haven't found nothing on docs neither on examples.

Environment:

ember-cli:

```
$ ember -v
ember-cli: 2.10.1
node: 6.9.2
os: darwin x64
```

chrome console:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 2.10.2
DEBUG: Ember Data : 2.11.3
DEBUG: jQuery     : 3.1.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe by design, the event is only sent to a corresponding controller or component, as mentioned (though not explicitly) in [the actions documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/templates/actions/).

So one solution would be to create a `myroute` controller (or create a component to encapsulate the behavior), and declare the action there.

Otherwise you could include the [ember-route-action-helper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-route-action-helper) and reach your action with something like:

```
{{#bs-button onClick=(route-action "actionTest")}}Run test action{{/bs-button}}
```

Comment: Jup. Its confusing that closure actions can only trigger the controller, while context actions bubble up.

Comment: Yep this was it for me.  I had an action defined in the route, but since the action occurred in a closure (a `<select onchange=...>` element), I had to move the action to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it cannot find the action inside the controller because the **closure action** will NOT bubble up to the route and above (parent routes).

One way to solve it is to use `ember-route-action` which change the target when you invoke the action.

Another way is to use the traditional `sendAction` method (Although no recommend), which make the action call bubble up by default.

Comment: @roger's answer stated the 'ember way' to solve it, but I consider that the confusion happens due the reason that you've presented here: "The reason is that the closure action will NOT bubble up to the route and above" - maybe it helps another beginners. Thanks.